# Add parent link to its submenu

Tags: menus, walker

How to add parent link to its sub menu in navigation bar? I mean any hook, filter or custom navigation Walking?

You may know, this problem is coined from the feature of mobile menu, I cannot go to parent link URL because when I click, It just opens its sub menu.

Comment: Is this a menu created by `wp_nav_menu()`?

Comment: Yes it is created by 'wp_nav_menu()'